# Android Material Raised button different states

Tags: android, button, material-design

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7UTh2dExpSlRVWVU/components_buttons_main16.png

In the link above for Material guidelines, the colored raised button has different states and the doc gives the specifications

Minimum width: 88dp
Height: 36dp
Normal color: 500 
Hover color: 600 
Pressed color: 700 
Disabled text: 30% #FFFFFF 
Disabled button: 12% #FFFFFF

Does anyone know what do these colors mean when they say 500, 600 and 700? Also is setting the elevation on the button enough? Do I need to change the elevation when the button is in the pressed state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are referring to the shade of color based on the published color guide:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

[image: red palette]